# proof of inequality with absolute-value and function

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, inequality

> Prove that if $|f'(x)| \leq M$, for all $x \in [a,b]$, then $$f(a)-M(b-a)\leq f(b) \leq f(a)+M(b-a)$$

---

What I tried so far:

Proof.
Let $$x \in [a,b]$$

Assume $$|f'(x)|\leq M$$

Show $$f(a)-(Mb-Ma)\leq f(b) \leq f(a)+(Mb-Ma)$$

By assumption that $f'$ defined on $[a,b]$, we have following:

$f$ is cts on [a,b], Also differentiable on (a,b)

By MVT have $\exists c \in (a,b) s.t.$

$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

by assumption also have $-M\leq f'(x) \leq M$

That $$c \in (a,b),\text{ have }-M \leq f'(c) \leq M$$

Have $$-M \leq \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \leq M$$

Therefore $$f(a)-M(b-a)\leq f(b) \leq f(a)+M(b-a)\tag*{$\square$}$$

Is this proof correct, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You are not using the hypothesis at all. How do you get $|f(x)| \leq M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. (Perhaps you have copied $|f'(x)| \leq M$ as $|f(x)| \leq M$).

Counterexample: if $f(x)=\sqrt x$ on $[0,1]$ then the hypothesis holds with $M=1$ but the right hand inequality in the conclusion fails for $a$ and $b$ close to $0$.

Answer to the edited question: just apply MVT: $f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(x)$ for some $x$ and $-M \leq f'(x) \leq M$.  Can you complete the proof using this?

Comment: Thanks for you reponding, I had prove there exists some x in [a,b] s.t. statement hold with MVT, how do I show for any x in [a,b] statement still hold?

Comment: You are asked to prove some inequalities involving $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.  You are not asked to prove anything that involves an arbitrary point $x \in [a,b]$. My $x$ is same as your $c$.